# BeautifulSoup HTML getting src link

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm making a small web crawler using python 3.5.1 and requests module, which downloads all comics from a specific website.I'm experimenting with one page. I parse the page using BeautifulSoup4 like below:

```
import webbrowser
import sys
import requests
import re
import bs4

res = requests.get('http://mangapark.me/manga/berserk/s5/c342')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all("a", class_ = "img-link"):
    if(link):
        print(link)
    else:
        print('ERROR')
```

When I do `print(link)` there are the correct HTML parts I'm interested in, but when I try to get only the link in **src** using `link.get('src')` it only prints `None`.

I tried getting the link using:

```
img = soup.find("img")["src"]
```

and it was OK, but I want to have all the src links, not the first link.
I have little experience with beautifulSoup. Please point out what's going on. Thank you.

The sample HTML part from the website I'm interested in is:

```
<a class="img-link" href="#img2">
    <img id="img-1" class="img"
          rel="1" i="1" e="0" z="1" 
          title="Berserk ch.342 page 1" src="http://2.p.mpcdn.net/352582/687224/1.jpg"
          width="960" _width="818" _heighth="1189"/>        
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in one go using a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for img in soup.select("a.img-link img[src]"):
    print(img["src"])
```

Here, we are getting all of the `img` elements having an `src` attribute located under an `a` element with a `img-link` class. It prints:

```
http://2.p.mpcdn.net/352582/687224/1.jpg
http://2.p.mpcdn.net/352582/687224/2.jpg
http://2.p.mpcdn.net/352582/687224/3.jpg
http://2.p.mpcdn.net/352582/687224/4.jpg
...
http://2.p.mpcdn.net/352582/687224/20.jpg
```

---

If you still want to use the `find_all()`, you would have to nest it:

```
for link in soup.find_all("a", class_ = "img-link"):
    for img in link.find_all("a", src=True):  # searching for img with src attribute
        print(img["src"])
```

Comment: This elegantly solved my problem. So the find_all method returns an object for further parsing.