# Extract only image links from beautiful soup output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

I'm new to BeautifulSoup, and I've been trying to pull each image link out of a webpage using bs4 and requests. However, when I try to print each image link it spits out html and not a direct link to any images.

I've tried switching from using 'find' to using 'findAll', but that still doesn't solve my problem.

```
import bs4
import requests

req = requests.get('https://www.gnu.org/home.en.html')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, features='html.parser')

html = (soup.findAll('img'))

print(html)
```

I expected the output to be web url's such as 
    https://www.gnu.org/distros/screenshots/guixSD-gnome3-medium.jpg, but instead the output gives me html which looks like this.

```
[<img alt=" [A GNU head] " src="/graphics/heckert_gnu.transp.small.png"/>,
```

Comment: Extract the src attribute. This question is asked a lot so there are plenty of example to choose from. You need to extract in a loop or comprehension as findAll will return a list of all matches.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56943210/6241235 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367018/beautifulsoup-html-getting-src-link  ,  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+get+all+src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative link can be taken from the `src` attribute. You can use:

```
for im in html:
    print(im['src'])
```

Then, concatenating with the base URL, you can get the complete URL.